# Creating vertices at mouse position is very off

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to create a vertice at my mouse position with python. This is my code to get the location:

```
`       region = bpy.context.region
        space = bpy.context.space_data.region_3d
        x, y = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_x
        loc = bpy_extras.view3d_utils.region_2d_to_location_3d(region, space, (x, y), (0,0,0))
```

. This is what happens:[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add vert on left mouse click**

Further to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107548/15543) added code to add *vertex* on left mouse click. (Using method explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/72862/15543))  Added a list to class to hold the newly added vertices, as suggested via [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107585/add-created-vertices-to-a-list).

Things to note:

Vertex coordinates are  local coordinates, whereas the calculated 3d cursor position is a global coordinate. To convert global to local the global vector is multiplied by the objects matrix world inverted.

A class property for the matrix world inverted, similar to setting `cls.bm` for bmesh to avoid inverting the matrix each time.

When writing operators or panels, very rarely (if ever) do you need to access context via `bpy.context`.  If `context` is an argument use it.  I often use `context = bpy.context` atop of test scripts as a convenient way to later copy / paste into code where `context` is defined.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_location_3d

bmeshes = {}

class Modal(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal"
    bl_label = "Modal Op"
    bl_description = "Other thingy"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    bm = None
    added_verts = []

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object and context.object.type == 'MESH'

    @classmethod
    def bmesh(cls, context):
        me = context.edit_object.data
        cls.bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        self.bmesh(context)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

    def add_vert(self, loc):
        v = self.bm.verts.new(loc)
        self.added_verts.append(v)

        return v

    def modal(self, context, event):
        # no longer in edit mode
        if context.mode != 'EDIT_MESH':
            self.bm.free()
            self.bm = None
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        ob = context.edit_object
        me = ob.data
        if self.bm is None or not self.bm.is_valid:
            # in edit mode so try make a new bmesh
            self.bmesh(context)            
        if event.type == "LEFTMOUSE" and event.value == "PRESS":

            x, y = event.mouse_region_x, event.mouse_region_y
            region = context.region
            rv3d = context.space_data.region_3d

            loc = region_2d_to_location_3d(region, rv3d, (x, y), (0, 0, 0))        

            v = self.add_vert(ob.matrix_world.inverted() * loc)
            v.select = True

        if event.type in {"RIGHTMOUSE", "ESC"}:
            self.bm.verts.index_update()
            bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
            print("added", self.added_verts)            
            return {"CANCELLED"}

        if event.type in ["WHEELUPMOUSE","WHEELDOWNMOUSE","MIDDLEMOUSE","LEFTMOUSE"]:
            return{"PASS_THROUGH"}

        return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Modal)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Modal)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Btw. If you put minimal working code into your question it would be a lot easier to work out where your particular mistake is.